# Addition of days to all the date columns in pandas using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a `dataframe` of date strings which is a `subset` of big `data frame`.The first 5 `rows` of this `dataframe` are

```
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date1':['2020-06-16','2020-06-16','2020-06-17','2020-06-21','2020-06-11'],
     'date2':['2020-06-10','2020-06-10','2020-06-10','2020-06-10','2020-06-10'],
     'date3':['2018-12-20','2018-12-19','2019-09-20','2019-05-08','2020-06-13'],
     'date4':['2020-07-07','2020-06-30','2020-07-01','2020-07-03','2020-07-24']})
```

I have `declared` a `variable` called `new_date='2020-06-29'`

`Define a variable` called `diff_date` such that `diff_date=new_date-dates_df['date2']`
Then this `diff_date` should be added to all the `date values` in each `date column`which should be my `final_df`.
The steps I have taken so far are converting these values to `pd.to_datetime()` and got the difference also. Got final df with the given answer given.
############################
Modified the above data frame a bit and wrote a function like this.

```
dates_df=pd.DataFrame(
 {'date1':['2020-06-16','2020-06-16','2020-06-17','2020-06-21','2020-06-    
 11'],'date2':['2020-06-10','2020-08-10','2020-06-10','2020-09-13','2020-06- 
 10'],'date3':['2018-12-20','2018-12-19','2019-09-20','2019-05-08','2020-06- 
 13'],'date4':['2020-07-07','2020-06-30','2020-07-01','2020-07-03','2020-07- 
 24']}) 

def datechange_func(dataset,variablelist,new_run_date,temp_run_date=None):
   dataset[variablelist]=dataset[variablelist].apply(pd.to_datetime)
   li= list(dataset['date2'].unique())
   if dataset.loc[dataset['date2'].any().isin(li)]:
       dataset['date2'] = max(li)
   else:
       dataset['date2'] = temp_run_date

   diff = new_run_date - dataset['date2']

   dataset[variablelist]=dataset[variablelist].add(diff,axis=0)

   return dataset
```

`variablelist1=['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date4']`
`final_df=datechange_func(dates_df,variablelist1,new_run_date,temp_run_date=None)`

It should `update dates_df['date2']` to get the `maximum unique value` in all the rows of `date2 column`
But I get this error
`TypeError: invalid_op() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna'`
How to rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.to_datetime` convert the date like columns to pandas datetime series, then use `DataFrame.add` along `axis=0` to add `diff` to the dataframe:

```
dates_df = dates_df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
diff = pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29') - dates_df['date2']
final_df = dates_df.add(diff, axis=0)
```

Result:

```
print(final_df)
      date1      date2      date3      date4
0 2020-07-05 2020-06-29 2019-01-08 2020-07-26
1 2020-07-05 2020-06-29 2019-01-07 2020-07-19
2 2020-07-06 2020-06-29 2019-10-09 2020-07-20
3 2020-07-10 2020-06-29 2019-05-27 2020-07-22
4 2020-06-30 2020-06-29 2020-07-02 2020-08-12
```

Comment: `@Shubham Sharma` your answer is useful. I have modified the above question by writing `a function to update dates_df['date2'] column` to have `maximum unique value` in all the `date2 column values` But I am getting error. Can you help me with this

Comment: @ruby Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220504/ds11)